# How to block all email related traffics

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, email-server, ubuntu-18.04

I'm recently getting warnings for one of my servers from its provider about sending spam emails.

As I don't use the server to send emails, I removed postfix/sendmail, removed MX record from my domain, limited SPF record, blocked outgoing traffic on port 25 and 567 and removed all unnecessary software from my server. But the problem is still there, I'm stilling getting warnings from spamhaus and abuseat, reporting there was more than 10 spam emails in last 24 hours.

I also checked email logs and they didn't have any log of outgoing emails, so I think postfix/sendmail weren't the problem.

The question is if there's any other way to send emails without using an SMTP relay and with the ports being blocked on firewall and where should I look next?

Third-party software running on server: Nginx(used to redirect or proxy), Ocserv, Gitea, Taiga, Teamspeak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly SMTP is normally on port 25 (which you've blocked) and 587 for SMTP submission (your question mentions port ***567*** which isn't useful), also possibly port 465 (SMTPS), so those are the ports to block, although 465, 587 typically would expect/need authentication so they would be unusual routes to send spam.

Do check if the emails are really being sent from the server / IP address you're investigating, and do check that you are indeed blocking those ports (esp. 25) - try telnet-ing from the server to port 25 on a known remote mail server - you should get a prompt if the port is still open, in which case the port isn't blocked (example to a gmail server),

```
$ telnet alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
Trying 2a00:1450:4010:c03::1b...
Connected to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP c14si24561520lji.153 - gsmtp
quit
221 2.0.0 closing connection c14si24561520lji.153 - gsmtp
Connection closed by foreign host.
$
```

maybe you get (un)lucky there. If the above don't explain what's happening here's a few more ideas,

Is someone spoofing your domain (from a different server they control)?

Can your server relay (via port 25, 465 or 587) via a different machine within your own organisation? The initial IP would then be the offending machine, even if the email exits your organisation from this other machine.

Note that a machine doesn't need a mail server installed to be able to send email: It can do it all via the equivalent of a telnet session to port 25 on a remote system - so mail server logs often don't show abuse of e.g. a web server where server-side scripts may have been added or compromised.

You mention that you've added an SPF record, that's a good idea to specify what machines are expected to be originating email for your domain; you may also like to consider adding DKIM and DMARC to increase that measure, although they're more complex to setup than SPF.

(prompted by Pooya's comment below) if you've using any VPNs, also consider if the VPN might provide a back door for traffic to leave the server.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer though I already solved the problem, your answer could be so much helpful at the time I was struggling with my server

Comment: The problem was that I used some tutorial to setup my vpn server and I didn't actually check all the commands I was copying in depth. So I ended up having a rule in iptables to forward all the ports from vpn to public interface, and one infected vpn client was sending email spams.

Comment: Pooya: Updated my answer to include mention of VPNs as another possible cause.